# Attempted import error: 'Footer' is not exported from 'dependency-C'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, babeljs

I'm working on a Next.js 9.0.5 (Node 16.20) project called **project-A** which has a dependency called **dependency-B**, which in turn has a dependency on **dependency-C**. When I try to build **project-A** using `npm run build` (which runs `rm -rf .next && next build`), I encounter the following error:

> ./node_modules/dependency-A/containers/Layout/LayoutContainer.js
>
> Attempted import error: 'Footer' is not exported from 'dependency-C'.
>
> Build error occurred
>
> Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors

However, I can see that the **Footer** component is being exported in the *index.esm.js* file of the sub-dependency as follows:

```
export { ComponentA, Footer$1 as Footer, Header$3 as Header, ComponentB, ComponentC };
```

This error happened after an update in **dependency-C** dependencies, not related to the **Footer** component.

How can I resolve this issue? Why the export appear OK but on build it occurs this import error?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: please provide minimal creation example